# How can I install the SSL certificates in a virtual environment in Python on a Mac?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, ssl-certificate

When I try to make a request to some urls, I get an SSLError. I think it is because I didn't install the right certificates in my Python3.9 virtual environment.
This is my code:

```py
import requests

url = "https://survey.unibz.it/opinio/s?s=12131"

r = requests.get(url)
print(r)
```

tjos os my[my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krQLz.png)
[the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8iBR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue with your code. That website has their certificate mis-configured.

You can skip validating their cert with

```py
r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
```

Keep in mind if you do this, it's possible you're not talking to the owners of the website but someone impersonating them.